# Writing List of Strings Outputted by Function to a File

Tags: python, list, file, indexing

I have a list of sentences that are the output of my function. They look like:

```
["['A', 'little', 'girl', 'spanks', 'her', 'blonde', 'hair', 'Of', 'a', 'twitching', 'nose', 'A', 'cigarette', 'butt.', '$']",
 "['From', 'another', 'town.', '$', 'The', 'arriving', 'train', 'All', 'my', 'sweaty', 'face', 'In', 'a', 'pine', 'tree.']",
 "['In', 'a', 'heavy', 'fall', 'of', 'flakes', 'And', 'timing', 'its', 'wing,', '\\xe2\\x80\\x93', 'A', 'leaf', 'chases', 'wind']",....

"['As', 'green', 'melon', 'splits', 'open', 'And', 'cools', 'red', 'tomatoes!', '$', 'In', 'a', 'breath', 'of', 'an']"]
```

Please excuse the words in the sentences. They're just experiments. I want to write these out to a file as just plain sentences.

I tried this:

```
def writeFile(sentences):
    with open("result.txt", "w") as fp:
        for item in sentences:
            fp.write("%s\n" % item)
```

But my output looks like this:

```
['A', 'little', 'girl', 'spanks', 'her', 'blonde', 'hair', 'Of', 'a', 'twitching', 'nose', 'A', 'cigarette', 'butt.', '$']
['From', 'another', 'town.', '$', 'The', 'arriving', 'train', 'All', 'my', 'sweaty', 'face', 'In', 'a', 'pine', 'tree.']
```

I am coding in Python 2. Can someone help?

Comment: I think what you want is `with open(....) as fp: fp.write(' '.join(word for word in sentences))`. But I can't be sure because I'm not sure if you intended on putting square brackets inside of the quoted string

Comment: Why have you stringified your list? That's going to make it much harder to do what you want. You need to fix the function that is producing this output, which you have not shown here.

Comment: @ZWiki - no need to to do `word for word in sentences` - `join()` will do the iteration for you, i.e. `' '.join(sentences)` (This is all an aside from the OP)

Answer (score 0):

If the item of your list is of the form of:

```
"['word0', 'word1', ...., 'wordn']"
```

then use `eval` to convert it to a `list` of words, and then `join` it to make a sentence as:

```
def writeFile(sentences):
    with open("result.txt", "w") as fp:
        for item in sentences:
            fp.write("{0}\n".format(" ".join(eval(item))))
```

If the item is already a list of words, then you dont need `eval` in the above code.

BTW, if you love list-comprehension and being functional, then you could do this:

```
def writeFile(sentences):
    with open("result.txt", "w") as fp:
        fp.write("\n".join(["".join(eval(item)) for item in sentences]))
```

But then it might not be very efficient if *sentences* has too many items in it, as it may end up using huge memory.